# Jenkins get proxy password

Tags: encryption, jenkins, groovy, proxy

I'm trying to decrypt the password which I have set for the Proxy configuration in Jenkins with the following results (the script is running in the Jenkins script console):

```
import jenkins.model.*
import jenkins.hudson.*

def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
def proxy = ProxyConfiguration.load()
def encrProxy = proxy.getEncryptedPassword()

// returns the encrypted Password {AQAAABAAAAAQhUGoRgQUrP6/***************** }
println(instance.proxy.getEncryptedPassword())
// returns the encrypted Password {AQAAABAAAAAQhUGoRgQUrP6/***************** }
println(proxy.getEncryptedPassword())

// returns empty strings
println proxy.getPassword()
// returns empty strings
println(instance.proxy.getPassword()) 

// returns empty strings
println hudson.util.Secret.decrypt(instance.proxy.getEncryptedPassword())
// returns empty strings
println hudson.util.Secret.decrypt(proxy.getEncryptedPassword())
```

Decryption of Passwords from `credentials.xml` works fine although.

But somehow Jenkins can decrypt the password, because the connection to validate the proxy is working fine.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me

```
def pass = jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance()?.proxy?.getPassword() 
println "password = $pass"
```

if we are talking about setting proxy password in `Advanced` tab of `Jenkins > Plugin Manager`

Comment: Thanks! After some research I found the reason, why the password field is set and a encrypted string si written to the proxy config. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28534